# C++: Will the memory leak in the following situations?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

The title is the question.

I still don't quite understand the behavior of dynamically allocated storages.

```
#include <utility>
int main() {
    // Case 1:
    volatile char *c1 = new char; // I'm gonna make these volatile, so the compiler won't change the code.
    volatile char *d1 = c1;
    delete d1;
    // Case 2:
    volatile char *c2 = new char[4];
    volatile char *d2 = c2;
    delete []d2;
    // Case 3:
    volatile char *c3 = new char;
    volatile char *d3 = std::move(c3);
    delete d3;
    // Case 4:
    volatile char *c4 = new char[4];
    delete c4++;
    delete []c4;
    // Case 5:
    volatile char *c5 = new char[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        delete c5++;
    return 0;
}
```

Will the memory leak in each situation?

Comment: Cases 4 and 5 are undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are under the assumption that `new char[5]` performs 5 separate `new`s for individual `char`s.  (To me that seems to explain why you came up with cases 4 and 5).

But this is not the case; For example, `c4` points to a single block of allocated storage that is (at least) large enough to hold 4 `char`s.  You cannot delete individual parts of it, you can only delete *all* of it.

The difference between `new/delete` and `new[]/delete[]` is explained quite well in the [C++ Super FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#allocate-array).

In your program:

```
// Case 1:
volatile char *c1 = new char; // Allocates enough space for 1 char
volatile char *d1 = c1;
delete d1;                    // Frees the space allocated
// Case 2:
volatile char *c2 = new char[4]; // Allocates enough space for a 4-char array
volatile char *d2 = c2;
delete []d2;                     // Frees that space
// Case 3:
volatile char *c3 = new char;    // Same as in case 1
volatile char *d3 = std::move(c3); // c3 is not nullptr
delete d3;                       // Same as in case 1
// Case 4:
volatile char *c4 = new char[4]; // Same as in case 2
delete c4++;                     // should be delete[], then same as case 2
delete []c4;                     // undefined behavior
// Case 5:
volatile char *c5 = new char[4]; // Same as in case 2
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    delete c5++;                 // doesn't make sense, undefined behavior
return 0;
```

Answer (score 8):

Cases 1 through 3: No leaks.

Cases 4 and 5; the deallocations result in undefined behaviour. You are deleting from a pointer that does not have the value as originally allocated.

Why are there no leaks with 1 to 3? You match the appropriate `delete` or `delete[]` with the used `new` or `new[]`; and they are matched in pairs, one de-allocation for each allocation.

I assume that the sample is simple as provided to demonstrate the allocations, but be warned that the pointers are not being "reset" to `NULL` (or `nullptr`) so any access to the previously allocated memory once deallocated is undefined.

---

Side note on the `std::move`, does it make the `c3` pointer `nullptr`? No it doesn't. The `std::move` doesn't actually "move" anything, it just changes the value category, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14679830/3747990) and [some sample code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf932e89168acbf9).

Answer (score 6):

Case 4 and 5 are undefined behaviour, so it's impossible to say whether or not the memory leaks.

For the other cases, the memory will not leak. However, it's worth stating that using `new` and `delete` at all is truly terrible and you should always use resource managing classes to hold the memory. Or to put it more simply, you shouldn't need to ask this question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:**

```
volatile char *c1 = new char; 
volatile char *d1 = c1;
delete d1;
```

No memory Leaks. You are allocating memory and `c1` points to it. Then a copy of the pointer `c1` is happend (not the data). So d1 point to the same place that `c1` points to now. Then, deleting `d1` is equal to delete `c1`.

**Case 2:**

```
volatile char *c2 = new char[4];
volatile char *d2 = c2;
delete []d2;
```

Same as above except that you are allocating a sequence of memory and deleting a sequence of memory. So, no leaks.

**Case 3:**

```
volatile char *c3 = new char;
volatile char *d3 = std::move(c3);
delete d3;
```

You first allocate a memory and `c3` points to it. Now you called a `move` operation. This `move` operation will move the address that `c3` is holding to `d3` without any change or move or copy on the actual data. After that, you deleted `d3` which actually point to the same place that `c3` was pointing to. So, no leaks.

**Case 4&5**: Undefined behaviour as other answers stated.

Comment: In case 3, will c3 be nullptr after std::move?

Comment: NOT 100%.. No it will not