# Rvalue and lvalue references as member variable in a class - Valid?

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, rvalue-reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class X
{
  public:
  int& a;
  int&& b;

  X(int& c, int && d):a(c), b(std::move(d))
  {

  }
};

X* x = nullptr;
void fun()
{

    std::cout<<"Fun\n";
    int l = 8;
    int r = 9;
    std::cout << &(l) << std::endl;
    std::cout << &(r) << std::endl;
    x = new X(l, std::move(r));    
}

int main()
{
  fun();

  std::cout << x->a << std::endl;
  std::cout << &(x->a) << std::endl;

  std::cout << x->b << std::endl;
  std::cout << &(x->b) << std::endl;

}
```

=> Will values of member variable references (`lvalue` and `rvalue`) be garbage?
 I am seeing different behavior across different compilers. So wanted to know what c++ standard says about this.

Comment: `rvalue` *reference* as a *data member* isn't going to end well.... BTW, you [can't really move integral types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679605/do-built-in-types-have-move-semantics)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding reference members to local variables, which will be destroyed when get out of the function `fun()`. After that, both references become dangled, any dereference on them leads to UB.

This is true for both lvalue and rvalue reference members.